# Black screen when taking a screenshot of video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, graphics-card, youtube, screenshot

This is a weird one I am struggling to find answers for. I have a Windows 10 laptop with OneDrive which allows for automatic saving of any screenshots I take. Well, I went to take a screenshot of a video on Crunchyroll and the video itself turned out **black** but the subtitles overlayed still showed up. See this picture below as an example:

[A screenshot of what happens. Video is paused, should have a character in frame, but when I take the screenshot, the video is dark except the subtitles and play button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EogFC.png)

I updated all my graphics drivers and browsers and even opened an old laptop to see if it happened on there as well, to which it didn't. So can someone help me understand why my laptop will not screenshot video? I decided to test if it happens to other video sources like YouTube, Prime Video or what have you and:

Videos on Prime showed up black.
YouTube videos showed up just fine.
Twitter videos showed up just fine.

Is there something I need to do to make screenshots of videos work on the other platforms that run similar to Amazon Prime Video or Crunchyroll?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you take screenshots? `Win+Shift+S` works fine for me on Crunchyroll. `cmd /c d:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -i desktop -frames:v 1 -f image2 "d:\tmp\screenshot_%date:~6,4%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.%time:~9,2%.png"` works acceptable.

Comment: I have the same problem with Crunchyroll on Mac